# Defining a vector of variables in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, animations, animate

I have the following animation in beamer:

[image: Random points neighborhood]

with the following code (probably not optimal):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=persistence]
\animate<1-10>
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{5cm}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,10} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[radius=2pt]
    \only<\n>{
        \node  at (-1,6){};
        \node  at (6.5,0){};
        \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.2]
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (1,1) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (2.3,1.1) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (4.5,0.8) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (5.1,1.8) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (0.4,3.3) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (2.1,2.8) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (3.8,3.5) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (4.8,4.2) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (0.8,4.9) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (2.1,4.1) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (3.8,2.0) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (3.5,0.6) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (3.0,5.0) circle (2+3*\n pt);   
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (4.1,5.1) circle (2+3*\n pt);          
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] (0.9,2.1) circle (2+3*\n pt);
        \end{scope}
        \filldraw[red] (1,1) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (2.3,1.1) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (4.5,0.8) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (5.1,1.8) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (0.4,3.3) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (2.1,2.8) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (3.8,3.5) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (4.8,4.2) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (0.8,4.9) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (2.1,4.1) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (3.8,2.0) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (3.5,0.6) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (3.0,5.0) circle ;   
        \filldraw[red] (4.1,5.1) circle ;          
        \filldraw[red] (0.9,2.1) circle ;
        }   
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
    \filldraw[red] (1,1) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (2.3,1.1) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (4.5,0.8) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (5.1,1.8) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (0.4,3.3) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (2.1,2.8) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (3.8,3.5) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (4.8,4.2) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (0.8,4.9) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (2.1,4.1) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (3.8,2.0) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (3.5,0.6) circle ;
        \filldraw[red] (3.0,5.0) circle ;   
        \filldraw[red] (4.1,5.1) circle ;          
        \filldraw[red] (0.9,2.1) circle ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now, with the same set of points (the reds circles) I need to create an animate graph on the right side of the slide, where an edge between point $P$ and $Q$ will appear if the intersection between the neighborhoods is not empty.  Is it possible with Tikz?
The solution, that I have in mind is to define a vector for the points and then use two nested for. But I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the first part of the requirements, the TikZ `\foreach` command can parse a list of coordinates which can be stored in a macro. The following illustrates how it can be done. It should be straightforward to adapt the code for the required use-case:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\pointlist{
  (1.0,1.0), (2.3,1.1), (4.5,0.8), 
  (5.1,1.8), (0.4,3.3), (2.1,2.8),
  (3.8,3.5), (4.8,4.2), (0.8,4.9), 
  (2.1,4.1), (3.8,2.0), (3.5,0.6),
  (3.0,5.0), (4.1,5.1), (0.9,2.1) 
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=2pt]
  \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.2]
    \foreach \point in \pointlist
      \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] \point circle [radius=5pt];
   \end{scope}
   \foreach \point in \pointlist
     \filldraw[red] \point circle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And assuming I understand the second part:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\pointlist{
  (1.0,1.0), (2.3,1.1), (4.5,0.8), 
  (5.1,1.8), (0.4,3.3), (2.1,2.8),
  (3.8,3.5), (4.8,4.2), (0.8,4.9), 
  (2.1,4.1), (3.8,2.0), (3.5,0.6),
  (3.0,5.0), (4.1,5.1), (0.9,2.1) 
}
\foreach \N in {1,...,10}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=2pt]
  \useasboundingbox (-1,-.5) rectangle (6.25,6.25);
  \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.2]
    \foreach \point in \pointlist
      \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] \point circle [radius=2pt+3*\N];
   \end{scope}
   \foreach \point in \pointlist
     \filldraw[red] \point circle;
   \foreach \P [count=\i] in \pointlist
     \foreach \Q [count=\j]in \pointlist {
       \ifnum\j>\i
       \else
         \path \P coordinate (P) \Q coordinate (Q);
         \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{P}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{Q}{center}}
         \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
         \pgfmathparse{int(veclen(\x,\y)/2 < 2+3*\N)}
         \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
           \draw [thick] (P) -- (Q);
         \fi
       \fi
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Following amorvincomni's answer, here is an alternative way of doing things using the `math` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\def\pointlist{
  (1.0,1.0), (2.3,1.1), (4.5,0.8), 
  (5.1,1.8), (0.4,3.3), (2.1,2.8),
  (3.8,3.5), (4.8,4.2), (0.8,4.9), 
  (2.1,4.1), (3.8,2.0), (3.5,0.6),
  (3.0,5.0), (4.1,5.1), (0.9,2.1) 
}
\foreach \N in {1,...,10}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=2pt]
  \useasboundingbox (-1,-.5) rectangle (14.25,6.25);
  \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.2]
    \foreach \point in \pointlist
      \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] \point circle [radius=2pt+3*\N];
   \end{scope}
   \foreach \point in \pointlist
     \filldraw[red] \point circle;
   \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
     \foreach \point in \pointlist
       \filldraw[red] \point circle;
     \foreach \P [count=\i] in \pointlist
       \foreach \Q [count=\j]in \pointlist {
         \ifnum\j>\i
           \tikzmath{%
             coordinate \p, \q, \r;
             \p = \P; \q = \Q; 
             \pq = veclen(\px-\qx, \py-\qy)/2;
             \d = 2pt+3*\N;
             if (\pq < \d) then {
               { 
                 \draw \P -- \Q;
                 \foreach \R [count=\k] in \pointlist {
                   \ifnum\k>\j
                     \tikzmath{%
                       \r = \R;
                       \pr = veclen(\px-\rx, \py-\ry)/2;
                       \qr = veclen(\qx-\rx, \qy-\ry)/2;             
                       if (\pr < \d) && (\qr < \d) then {
                         { 
                           \fill [fill=yellow, fill opacity=.2] \P -- \Q -- \R;                        
                         };
                       };
                     }
                   \fi
                 }
               };
             };
           }
        \fi
      }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it answer completely to my question!

Comment: I have added some non requested improvements

Comment: @amorvincomni I have incorporated your improvements into my answer, also showing a use for the `math` library.

Comment: my code is a little bit different, because filled triangles appear only when there is a nonempty intersection of three neighborhoods . So not filled triangle are allowed (different from your implementation). For this reason I need to calculate the circumcenter.

Comment: @amorvincomni ah yes, I see that now.

Comment: Mark: do you know why my example trotters?

Comment: @amorvincomni possibly a bounding box problem (?). When you create the lines for the intersections they are 2cm long which for some of the triangles may result in a point further out than in previous frames. you could try using `\useasboundingbox` to manually set the bounding box to prevent this issue (if this is what is causing the problem).

Comment: I have fixed it by putting the first \for cycle inside the picture.

Comment: I'm trying to use the math library, but I'm not able to install it. Apparently my latex version is updated. Can you help me? (I have posted a new question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218664/tikz-library-math) )

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun: from the good answer of Mark Wibrow I have made the following code. It is not optimal, but it  creates filled triangles when the intersection of the three neighbourhood corresponding to the vertices of the triangle is not empty:

```
\begin{frame}[label=persistence]
\animate<1-27>
\scalebox{.8}{%
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{5cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[radius=2pt]%        
    \foreach \n in {1,...,27}% 
    {%      
    \only<\n>{%
        \useasboundingbox (-1,-1.5) rectangle (6.25,7.25);      
        \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.2]
            \foreach \point in \pointlist {
        \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=black] \point circle (5+\n pt);
        }
        \end{scope}
        \foreach \point in \pointlist {
        \filldraw[red] \point circle;}
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{5cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[radius=2pt]
            \useasboundingbox (-1,-1.5) rectangle (6.25,7.25);              
            \foreach \n in {1,...,27}{%
                \only<\n>{%
                    \foreach \point in \pointlist
                        \filldraw[red] \point circle;
                    \foreach \P [count=\i] in \pointlist
                        \foreach \Q [count=\j]in \pointlist {
                        \ifnum\j>\i
                            \path \P coordinate (P) \Q coordinate (Q);
                            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{P}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{Q}{center}}
                            \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                            \pgfmathparse{int(veclen(\x,\y)/2 < 5+\n)}
                            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                                \draw [thick] (P) -- (Q);
                                \foreach \T [count=\k] in \pointlist {  
                                \ifnum\k>\j
                                \path \P coordinate (P) \T coordinate (T);
                                \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{P}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{T}{center}}
                                \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                                \pgfmathparse{int(veclen(\x,\y)/2 < 5+\n)}
                                \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                                \coordinate  (A) at ($(P)!0.5!(Q)$);
                                \coordinate  (C) at ($(P)!0.5!(T)$);
                                \coordinate  (A') at ($(A)!2cm!90:(P)$);
                                \coordinate  (C') at ($(C)!2cm!90:(P)$);
                                \coordinate  (O) at (intersection of A--A' and C--C');
                                \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{O}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{T}{center}}
                                \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                                \pgfmathparse{int(veclen(\x,\y) < 5+\n)}
                                \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                                \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{O}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{Q}{center}}
                                \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                                \pgfmathparse{int(veclen(\x,\y) < 5+\n)}
                                \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                                \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{O}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{P}{center}}
                                \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                                \pgfmathparse{int(veclen(\x,\y) < 5+\n)}
                                \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                                \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.3]
                                    \draw[fill=yellow] (P) --  (Q) --  (T) -- cycle;
                                    \end{scope}
                                \fi
                                \fi
                                \fi
                                \fi
                                \fi
                                }%
                            \fi
                        \fi
                        }%
                }
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{column}
\end{columns}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the results:

[image]