# Tikz library math

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, tikzlibrary

Following the answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216352/defining-a-vector-of-variables-in-tikz) I tried to run the code proposed by Mark in the third "code window".
What I obtain is:

```
I can't find file `tikzlibrarymath.code.tex'
```

Runninig the terminal command

```
tlmgr update --all
```

I obtain the following

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: no updates available
```

So I suppose that my packages are updated. The question is: how to install properly the tikz library math?
In order to install it in a local dir, I have (partially) followed the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187193/how-to-install-tikz-pgf-libraries)
, but now I'm not able to find the repositories and the proper Tex Directory Structure.

Comment: Do you have TikZ v3.00? you can put `\pgfversion` in your document to see what it is.

Comment: @percusse: No v2.10. Have I to upgrade it? If yes, how can I do?

Comment: Yes it is a recent library addition happened after 2.10

Comment: @percusse: following the manual for debian I have installed the last pgf with the command line `sudo aptitude install pgf` but my tex seem to read the older version 2.10. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes. Debian's TeX Live is ancient. If you want up-to-date stuff, [install vanilla from upstream](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For having the newest available libraries and packages on Debian, install the original TeX Live from: http://tug.org/texlive/

Debian repository versions are usually a bit behind, naturally.

Note, that software may depend on Debian versions though. For example, if you would install a TeX editor from Debian repositories, it may depend on Debian TeX packages to be installed. You can force installation or work around it, such as with the `equivs` tool, or use TeXworks from TeX Live itself or a separately installed independent editor.